# scikit-image can not import an image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

#### Environment:

- Python 3.7.0
- After creating a virtualenv, scikit-image is via pip installed.
- `scikit-image==0.16.2`, `Pillow==7.1.1`
- Anaconda on Linux

#### Source Code:

```
from skimage.io import imread
file_path = "image_you_like.png"
img = imread(file_path, plugin="pil", as_gray=False)
```

#### Expected Result:

`img` is a numpy array of an image.

#### Actual Result:

Do not trust the line number, because I inserted a few print functions.

```
~/Python/experiment/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py in _seek(self, frame, rewind)
    789 
    790             try:
--> 791                 cid, pos, length = self.png.read()
    792             except (struct.error, SyntaxError):
    793                 break

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

#### Question

How can I prevent this error and read an image?

After some analysis I found that `imread` works if `plugin="matplotlib"` or `plugin="imageio"`. The problem is that some functions such as `skimage.data.camera` call `imread` with `plugin="pil"` and therefore I can not try any sample image of `scikit-image`.

[EDIT]

```
from skimage.io.manage_plugins import plugin_store
print(plugin_store["imread"])
```

prints the following

```
[('imageio', <function imread at 0x7efe39112c20>), ('matplotlib', <function imread at 0x7efe37f51290>)]
```

So "pil" can not be found in the list.

Comment: You must have checked this but "Does the image exists in the `cwd`?" I ask because I tried the code above and it worked.

Comment: It definitely exists. Therefore the code will work (on my env) if I change only the plugin option.

Comment: What I meant was I tried with `plugin=pil` and it worked. Could you explain yourself better?

Comment: I understand what you meant. I meant that the image does exist.

Comment: Can you try `io.find_available_plugins()` and check if `pil` is in there?

Comment: I found `'pil': ['imread', 'imsave', 'imread_collection']` in the result.

Comment: You could try `io.use_plugin('pil', 'imread')` to load the plugin... And then try loading the image..Let me know if it works to write an answer, cause this is a very interesting thing. Also, why wouldn't it be available from the start?

Comment: I got the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was [reported on github](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4518).

As a user the easiest solution is to downgrade the version to 6.2.2.